# Interface throw error not able to understand

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Here is my code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export interface Lang {
  name:string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})

export class AppComponent {

  lang:Lang = "Eng";//getting error as not assignable..!?
  readonly name: string = 'Angular';
  version: number = 7;

  onVersionRelease(): void {
    this.version += 1;
  }
}
```

[Live Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-scw7eu)

why the `Eng` not assignable to interface string lang? any help me to understand. as well how to create interface for string property then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interface require that your object have to be declared like this:

```
  lang: Lang = {name: 'Eng'};
```

Comment: But I require to declare just plain string.. can't I declare plain string alone? so the interface only for object and array?

Comment: I think so, because there's already the type string to declare strings...so you don't need to declare a new type. You can do lang: string = 'Eng'